# If, else statement with dialog got error (below are my Log cat error)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-dialog

I have create this if, else statement, if the Name is not null it will insert in, but if its not it will show dialog. here is my codes. I have input in if else statement, so by right if name is not null it can should store the stuff, which it did, but when the name is null the dialog doesnt pop up. I dont know why. Is there something wrong with my codes? When the Name is NULL, i press the btnAdd the application straight away stop working. without the dialog appearing.

```
Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            EditText etDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDesc);
            EditText etStart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etStart);
            EditText etEnd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnd);
            EditText etPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);

            //from passing class
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String Name = intent.getExtras().getString("Name");

            if (Name != null){

            TripDetails details = new TripDetails(etDesc.getText().toString(),
                    etStart.getText().toString(), etEnd.getText()
                            .toString(),etPhone.getText().toString(),Name);
            Trip.add(details);
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            etDesc.setText("");
            etStart.setText("");
            etEnd.setText("");
            etPhone.setText("");
            getIntent().removeExtra("Name"); 
            }
            else {

                //incase they never key in the "Name"
                //put dialo
                 AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPage.this);

                    dlgAlert.setMessage("wrong password or username");
                    dlgAlert.setTitle("Error Message...");
                   dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                   dlgAlert.create().show();

                    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {




                        }
                    });
            }


        }
    });




01-15 20:45:26.104: W/dalvikvm(6394): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught    exception (group=0x416162a0)
```

01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394):     at com.example.nextbusstopv1.MainPage$1.onClick(MainPage.java:95)
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-15 20:45:26.114: E/AndroidRuntime(6394):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 20:45:26.144: E/android.os.Debug(2273): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error

Comment: Be careful with Java syntax. You're name variable may not have a caps.

Comment: haha i will :). yeap all is the same

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid passing 2 times the setPoisitiveButton option. And avoid passing it after creating and showing the dialog too.

Answer (score 1):

Try Like

```
AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPage.this);

                    dlgAlert.setMessage("wrong password or username");
                    dlgAlert.setTitle("Error Message...");
                    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);


                    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                   // create alert dialog
                   AlertDialog alertDialog = dlgAlert.create();

                 // show it
                 alertDialog.show();
                    });
```

Comment: Same error again. My problem is that because i need to press the bttn, after pressing it, if it's else the application will stop working. i dont know what is wrong

Comment: i posted Logcat above

Comment: i copy those red lines out only. Do i need to copy everything? sry im new.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Java don't recognize equal("==") or not equals (!=) Condition. I faced several issues in our Career when I Used this type conditions (Str==strname) so after that the condition was not true if str equals strname, Then I review some posts, so after then when I used (str.equals(strname)) so this satisfied my condition. try to use (!Name.equals(null)) instead of (Name != null). I think this is the Problem in your Code.

Comment: kindly add additional code in your application for dlgAlert.setIcon(0);